# Spreadsheet with StarCraft 2 units statistics

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a spreadsheet with unit states for StarCraft 2?

The ones I found are either not up-to-date is (e.g.
[this one](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Agw3AqYg3w7ddFpRYmFlN29Ybm9nTFktX0JfdDlKVHc&authkey=CMOApp8E&hl=en) is clearly not fro 1.4.3 patch) or not comprehensive (e.g. one on the [Blizzard site](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/) and the same thing [in GoogleDocs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlrXv_MKy9dcdGlXc0tWMldEcGVCNHFZVFVnelVja1E)).

Comment: How is the one on the blizzard site not comprehensive? When you click on the units it takes you to the full stats of the unit.

Comment: @Sorean The main isn't. When clicked, it is not _a spreadsheet_; the question is not about 'stats' (there are plenty possibilities) but about 'stats in spreadsheet form'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [that](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Protoss_Unit_Statistics) is what you're looking for.